# Persisting disconnected POCO entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, poco

I'm working with disconnected POCO objects.

When I persist a single object, it works fine!

The problem starts when I want to persist related objects.

For example:

Retrieving object from Data layer:

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext ())
{
    return ctx.Users.First();  
}
```

This object goes back to Business layer and there, I add some child records, see below (just to ilustrate):

```
objectUser.Permissions.Add(new Permission());
objectUser.Permissions.Add(new Permission());
```

Permissions is a navigation to User Permissions.

And then, I want to persist this objectUser back to database, then I do:

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext ())
{
    ctx.Users.Attach(objectUser);
    ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(objectUser, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    ctx.SaveChanges();                       
}
```

But on first line inside using, I get the error: "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key".

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong?

I just want to persist objects and their related objects.

---

I've tried to detach the entity, but in this case I loose all related objects, and I need these related objects so that I can add/remove.

After that, I wanted to persist them back to database.

Am I doing a stupid architecture??

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that the `objectUser` object is still attached to the context used to retrieve it from the database. If you require this workflow where you have two different contexts defined you must detach the `objectUser` from the initial context. One way to do this is to turn off object tracking on the `objectUser` context object. Alternately you could manually detach the object from the context.

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext ())
{
    //EF 4.1 - ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ctx.Users.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

    return ctx.Users.First();  
}
```

Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/12/ef-merge-options-and-compiled-queries.aspx

Part 1 is all about the MergeOption property.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your reply.

The problem is that when detaching the entity, I loose all related objects. Is there a way so that I can get the entity and all its related objects in order to work with them?

Comment: you should be able to use Include for this, e.g. `return ctx.Users.Include("Permissions").First();`