# Entity Framework with WCF POCOs Referential Integrity Issue

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, poco

I have a fairly simple scenario where I can't seem to get the correct logic.  I am using a WCF Service with POCOs to read and write data to a database.  I have a keywords table that has a foreign key UserID linked to a UserProfile table.  I am adding and modifying the keywords collection but when I try to include the UserProfile in the GetKeywords method and then make some changes and call the StoreKeywords method I get Referential Integrity issues.  If I don't include the UserProfiles I can add and update no problem. I used the POCO generator with WCF support and modified the T4 to remove virtual and use the FixupCollections.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

GetKeywords service:

```
    public class Service : IService
    {
    public List<Keyword> GetKeywords()
    {
        var context = new myDBEntities();

        var query = from c in context.Keywords
                        .Include("UserProfile")
                    select c;

        //var query = from c in context.Keywords.Take(100)
        //            select c;

        return query.ToList();

    }
```

Client Code that calls GetKeywords makes some changes and then calls StoreKeywords:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Keyword> keylist;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateGrid();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myServiceClient client = new myServiceClient();

        List<Keyword> updates = new List<Keyword>();

        foreach (Keyword keyword in keylist)
        {
            if (keyword.State == State.Added)
            {
                keyword.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                updates.Add(keyword);
            }

            if (keyword.State == State.Modified)
            {
                keyword.EditDate = DateTime.Now;
                if (keyword.IsVoid == false) keyword.VoidDate = null;
                if (keyword.IsVoid == true) keyword.VoidDate = DateTime.Now;
                updates.Add(keyword);
            }
        }

        client.StoreKeywords(updates.ToArray());

        foreach (var kw in keylist)
        {
            kw.State = State.Unchanged;
        }

        PopulateGrid();
        gridControl1.RefreshData();
    }

    private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        myServiceClient client = new myServiceClient();

        keylist = new ObservableCollection<Keyword>(client.GetKeywords());

        gridControl1.ItemsSource = keylist;

    }
```

StoreKeywords service:

```
public string StoreKeywords(List<Keyword> keywords)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new myDBEntities())
            {
                context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                foreach (Keyword kw in keywords)
                {

                        context.Keywords.Attach(kw);
                        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(kw, StateHelpers.GetEquivalentEntityState(kw.State));

                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                return "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Always tell where (at which line of code) an exception occurs. Also the exception you mention in your comment below.

Comment: The Exception occured in context.Keywords.Attach(kw); but it is due to the GetKeywords method including the UserProfile

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet i found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315654/persisting-disconnected-poco-entities) which was not apparent to me at all.  The issue was in the GetKeyword() method because it was attempting to track the merge.  the new GetKeywords() method:

```
public List<Keyword> GetKeywords()
    {
        var context = new InstanexDBEntities();
        context.Keywords.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; 

        var query = from c in context.Keywords
                        .Include("UserProfile").Take(100)
                    select c;

        return query.ToList();


    }
```

Comment: Now I am still running into an issue when I try to modify multiple keywords at once which is telling me...(An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.)

Comment: It turns out the real issue is that trying to .include the parent UserProfile along with the child keyword doesn't really make sense to Entity Framework.  Removing the Userprofiles from the GetKeywprds method and then calling another getUserProfiles on the client is a better approach.